How to append the name of a sublist vector as a named element within the vector
I have a list that contains web-traffic details.
In the process of rectangling the lists, I'd like to append a value to each vector in the named sublists which is the actual name of the sublist vector.
If I use this for example:
test_list %>% 
  map_depth(2, \(x) append(x, names(x)))

... I end up adding all the vector element names, whereas I want to append an element name of "campaign_type" with either the value "manual_campaign" or "google_ads_campaign" since those are the only 2 names for those sublist vectors.
Successfully the first sublist would have these elements:

campaign_id : NA
campaign_name : '(organic)'
...
marketing_tactic : NA
campaign_type : "manual_campaign"

I've been using purrr and the map family for rectangling so either base R or tidyverse is welcome.
Thanks.
Reprex data:
test_list <- structure(list(list(manual_campaign = list(campaign_id = NA_character_, 
    campaign_name = "(organic)", source = "bing", medium = "organic", 
    term = "(not provided)", content = "(not set)", source_platform = NA_character_, 
    creative_format = NA_character_, marketing_tactic = NA_character_), 
    google_ads_campaign = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL)), list(manual_campaign = list(campaign_id = NA_character_, 
    campaign_name = "(referral)", source = "Google", medium = "My Campaign", 
    term = "(not set)", content = "(not set)", source_platform = NA_character_, 
    creative_format = NA_character_, marketing_tactic = NA_character_), 
    google_ads_campaign = list(customer_id = "1111", account_name = "My Account", 
        campaign_id = "2222", campaign_name = "My Campaign Name", 
        ad_group_id = "3333", ad_group_name = "My Adgroup"))))```



Is this list data read from a XML document?

no, it's read from bigquery using bigrquery - it's downloaded directly as a list.

Here is another approach that allows to include the node list names directly when unnesting the list to a data.frame using the option how = "bind" in rrapply() from package rrapply (extension of base rapply()):
rrapply::rrapply(
  test_list, 
  condition = Negate(is.null),      ## skip NULLs
  how = "bind",                     ## bind to wide data.frame
  options = list(namecols = TRUE)   ## include list names
)

#>   L1                  L2 campaign_id    campaign_name source      medium
#> 1  1     manual_campaign        <NA>        (organic)   bing     organic
#> 2  2     manual_campaign        <NA>       (referral) Google My Campaign
#> 3  2 google_ads_campaign        2222 My Campaign Name   <NA>        <NA>
#>             term   content source_platform creative_format marketing_tactic
#> 1 (not provided) (not set)            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>
#> 2      (not set) (not set)            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>
#> 3           <NA>      <NA>            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>
#>   customer_id account_name ad_group_id ad_group_name
#> 1        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
#> 2        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
#> 3        1111   My Account        3333    My Adgroup


A solution could be using map_depth at level 1 and call mapply function into the nested list to get what you have asked:
test_list <-map_depth(test_list, 1, \(.x) mapply(\(x, y) {
  names(y)<-"campaign_type"
  c(x,y)
}
, x=.x
, y=names(.x)
, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
) 

Then, binding and put all into data frame:
new_dat<-test_list %>% 
  map_depth(2, vctrs::list_drop_empty) %>%
  map_depth(1,  bind_rows) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "mainlist") %>% 
  relocate(campaign_type, .after = mainlist) 

output:
  mainlist       campaign_type campaign_id    campaign_name source      medium           term   content source_platform creative_format marketing_tactic customer_id account_name ad_group_id ad_group_name
1        1     manual_campaign        <NA>        (organic)   bing     organic (not provided) (not set)            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
2        1 google_ads_campaign        <NA>             <NA>   <NA>        <NA>           <NA>      <NA>            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
3        2     manual_campaign        <NA>       (referral) Google My Campaign      (not set) (not set)            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>          <NA>
4        2 google_ads_campaign        2222 My Campaign Name   <NA>        <NA>           <NA>      <NA>            <NA>            <NA>             <NA>        1111   My Account        3333    My Adgroup

Hope this could help, but for sure there are other solutions as well.

{collapse} is powerful. unlist2d() has a recursive-argument set to TRUE (default).
collapse::unlist2d(test_list, idcols = paste0("L", 1:3)) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = L1:L2, names_from = L3, values_from = V1)

# A tibble: 3 × 15
     L1 L2       campaign_id campaign_name source medium term  content source_platform creative_format marketing_tactic customer_id account_name ad_group_id ad_group_name
  <int> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>         <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>           <chr>           <chr>            <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        
1     1 manual_… NA          (organic)     bing   organ… (not… (not s… NA              NA              NA               NA          NA           NA          NA           
2     2 manual_… NA          (referral)    Google My Ca… (not… (not s… NA              NA              NA               NA          NA           NA          NA           
3     2 google_… 2222        My Campaign … NA     NA     NA    NA      NA              NA              NA               1111        My Account   3333        My Adgroup   

Edit. The wide format may not be needed.
